# Suppose that X ∼ U ( $− π/2$ , $π/2$ ) . Find the pdf of Y = tan(X).

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that X ∼ U
$(−π/2,π/2$)
. Find the pdf of Y = tan(X). Make sure to define the
support of the density function.

My work so far: 
$F_Y(y) = P(Y < y) = P (tan(x) < y) = P (x < tan^{-1}(y)) = F_X(tan^{-1}(y)) = \int_{-\pi/2}^{tan^{-1}(y)} 1/\pi = tan^{-1}(y)/\pi + 1/2 -> derivative -> 1/(\pi + \pi y^{2})$

This is the cauchy distribution. Thanks for the help in the comments!

Comment: Double check the solution to your integral (keep in mind what to integrate with respect to). Also, you computed the CDF. Try taking a derivative and then I think you'll recognize the pdf (after you fix the solution to your integral)

Comment: Did you mean $\mathcal U(-\pi^2, \pi^2)$ or $\mathcal U(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ ?

Comment: Oops, I messed up in the title there. Editting it into the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have:

$$F_X(tan^{-1}(y)) = \int_{-\pi/2}^{tan^{-1}(y)} \frac{1}{\pi} dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\left(tan^{-1}(y) + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{\pi}tan^{-1}(y) + \frac{1}{2}$$.

Take a derivative with respect to $y$ and you'll end up with a very familiar distribution

Answer (score 0):

Here an other prove using the theorem of variable changing in probability. We can use it because $\phi(x) =tg(x)$ is a difeomorphism of classe $C^1$ on $[ -\frac{\pi}{2} ; \frac{\pi}{2} ] $ as $ \phi^{-1}(x)=arctg(x)$ exists and is necessary continuous because $(\phi^{-1}(x) )' = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and this derivative is continuous.

1- By definition we have that $E[g(X)] = \int g(x)f(x) dx$ with $f(x)$  the density probability of the r.v. $X$ .
$E[ g(tan(X)) ] = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^{\frac{\pi}{2}} g(tan(x))f(tan(x)) dtan(x)$ with $g$ a measurable function.

2- Changement of variable $ t = tan(x) \Rightarrow dt = (1+tan^2(x)) dx = (1+t^2)dx \Rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{1+t^2} $, moreover $- \infty <t< \infty$.
Hence: $E[ g(tan(X)) ] = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}} ^{\frac{\pi}{2}} g(tan(x))f(tan(x)) dtan(x) = E[ g(t) ] = \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} g(t) \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt $

3- From "2-" the density function is proportional to $\frac{ \alpha}{1+t^2}$.
$\int _{\pm \infty} \frac{ \alpha}{1+t^2} dx = \pi \alpha$ as we want it to be equal to $\alpha \pi = 1 \Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{1}{\pi}$
In conclusion the density function is $\frac{ 1}{1+t^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi}$