# The pdf of $\tan X$ when $X$ is Uniform

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\pi}, & \text{if } -\frac{\pi}{2} < x <\frac{\pi}{2} \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

Find the pdf of $Y = \tan(x)$.

My attempt:

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = P(\tan(x)\le y) = P(x\le \tan^{-1}(y))=F_X(\tan^{-1}y) = \begin{cases} 0,&\text{if } x<-\frac{\pi}{2} \\  \frac{1}{\pi}{\tan^{-1}y}, & \text{if } -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x <\frac{\pi}{2} \\ 1, & \text{if } x\geq \frac{\pi}{2} \end{cases}$$

$$ f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+x^2}, & \text{if } -\frac{\pi}{2} < x <\frac{\pi}{2} \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Typo in $f_Y(y)$: it is $y^2$, not $x^2$. And the support of $Y$ should include the domain of $y$. That is, $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2\implies y=\tan x\in \,?$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1698022/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}F_Y(y) &= P(Y\le y) \\&= P(\tan(\color{red}X)\le y) \\&= P(X\le \tan^{-1}(y))\\&=F_X(\tan^{-1}y) \\&=  \frac{1}{\pi}\left({\tan^{-1}y}+\frac{\pi}2 \right)\end{align}

$$ f_Y(y) =  \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+y^2} $$

Comment: why did you add $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the $tan^{-1}y$ for the cdf of Y?

Comment: For uniform distribution $U(a,b)$, its CDF when $x \in (a,b)$ is $\frac{x-a}{b-a}$. Here the $a$ is $-\frac{\pi}2$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh $tan^{-1}y \in (-\pi/2;\pi/2)$, why do you consider equalities and greater/less-than?

Comment: you are right, thanks.

Comment: This is a Cauchy distribution with $ x_0 = 0 $ and $ \gamma = 1 $.