# Let $U \sim \textrm{Unif}(0, \pi/ 2)$. Find the PDF of $\sin(U)$.

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

This is almost the same as [Suppose that X ∼ U ( $− π/2$ , $π/2$ ) . Find the pdf of Y = tan(X).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698022/suppose-that-x-%E2%88%BC-u-%E2%88%92-%CF%80-2-%CF%80-2-find-the-pdf-of-y-tanx), but making sure I am understanding the process:

> Let $U \sim \textrm{Unif}(0, \pi/ 2)$. Find the PDF of $\sin(U)$.

$$\begin{align} 
F_Y(y) &= P(Y<y) = P(\sin(u)<y) = P(u < \sin^{-1}(y)) \\
&=F_U(\sin^{-1}(y)) = \int_0^{\sin^{-1}(y)}\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}}du \\
&= \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}}u |_0^{\sin^{-1}(y)} \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\sin^{-1}(y) \\
\end{align} $$

That is the CDF. To find the PDF, take the derivative with respect to $y$ to get:

$$ \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} $$

1. Is the work & logic correct?
2. Is the support of $Y$ the same as the support for U: $[0,pi/2]$?

Comment: The support for $Y$ is $[0,1]$. Always good to confirm that the PDF integrates to 1 over $[0,1]$. In this case it does. You can compute the integral by substituting $y = \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Aditya Dua: The support for Y is [0,1]. Always good to confirm that the PDF integrates to 1 over [0,1]. In this case it does. You can compute the integral by substituting y=sinθ.