# Finding pdf of $\tan(X)$ when $X \sim U (-\pi ,\pi)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

This question is a particular case of the following:

[Suppose that X ∼ U ( $− π/2$ , $π/2$ ) . Find the pdf of Y = tan(X).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698022/suppose-that-x-%e2%88%bc-u-%e2%88%92-%cf%80-2-%cf%80-2-find-the-pdf-of-y-tanx)

I came up at the same solution in the following post, ignoring for a moment the real data of the problem, that is $X \sim U (-\pi ,\pi)$ and not $X \sim U ( -\pi/2 ,\pi/2)$.

Due to this change in the domain of $X$, I split the problem in 3 parts and summed up:

$P(-\pi/2 \le x \le \arctan(y))  +P(\pi/2 \le x \le \pi-\arctan(y))  +P(-\pi \le x \le - \pi + \arctan(y)) $

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [graph of $\tan(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+tan(x)+x%3D-pi..pi), you see that you have two cases:

If $y<0$, then:

$$P(Y\le y) = P(\tan(X)\le y)=\\P(-\pi/2\lt X\le \arctan(y))+P(\pi/2\lt x\le\arctan(y)+\pi)$$

If $y\ge0$, then:

$$P(Y\le y) = P(\tan(X)\le y)=\\P(-\pi\lt X\le \arctan(y)-\pi)+P(-\pi/2\lt x\le\arctan(y))+P(\pi/2\lt x\lt\pi)$$

In both cases:
$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}(2\arctan(y)+\pi)$$

By differentiation one gets:
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+y^2)}$$

Comment: when y $\ge 0$, is $P(\pi/2\lt x\le\arctan(y)+\pi)$ correct? because the first term on the summation is the left part on the graph ($-\pi, -\pi/2$) and the third term is the right part of the graph ($\pi/2, \pi$). While the term in the middle it seems me wrong and instead I would insert: $P(-\pi/2 \le x \le \arctan(y))$. Could you tell me if I'm wrong and explain from where it come from your term? .. I think that I miss something. does not the case Y$\ge 0$  include also the case Y$\le 0 $

Comment: Yes, you are right. Corrected.

Comment: the case y$\ge 0$ does not embed also the case when y $\le 0$?? indeed as third term in y$\ge 0$  you inserted the range on $\pi/2\lt x\lt\pi$ that is when y is $\le 0$

Comment: $X$ is continuous, so it doesn't matter whether a particular point of probability zero is included or excluded (and as a matter of fact $\tan(x)$ is not even defined for $x=\pm\pi/2$)

Comment: no, I didn't mean that.

Comment: What I wanted to ask is: you divided the problem in 2 cases, when y is lower than 0 and when is higher then 0, but since we are computing the cumulative distribution, when u compute P(Y<y) in the case that y is > 0, this atuomatically embed also the cases when y is lower then 0. indeed the third term that u wrote  in the case y > 0, that is: "P(/2<<)" is analysing the part of the graph that Is lower then 0.. so the first part of your resolution is useless..at least I think

Comment: @Alberto__ The [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+tan(x)+in+black%2C+-1+in+green%2C+1+in+red+x%3D-pi..pi) under the red line (for $y>0$) is made of three pieces, while the graph under the green line ($y<0$) is made only of two